# I bought the GTA premium online but don’t have the CESP

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I just bought the Premium Online GTA game, installed it, launched the game and I didn't receive any of the items. I've tried restarting the game but even that didn't work. Neither did it give me constructions on how to get the items. Instead of giving me instructions on how to get the items (What it's supposed to do) it just tells me that the CESP is availabe to purchase.

I basically just wasted 19,99 dollars..

- Yes, I'm atleast level 5+
- Yes, I've checked the sites for "FREE" items.

Comment: Can you explain what items you're referring to, and why you think you should have them?

Comment: I should have all the free items from the Criminal enterprise starter pack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pause the game and go to the Online section of the menu. Click on Criminal Enterprise Starter Pack and it will "activate" the items. You can then go to each item's respective store (e.g. Ammunation for guns), and the items in the pack will be made free. If you sort the items by price, you should be able to find them more easily.

Comment: that still doesn't work.